# Regarding maximal ideal space

Tags: banach-algebras, characters

Let $A$ be the set of all degree one polynomials of the form $a+bx$ with complex coefficients $a$ and $b$. Define the multiplication on $A$ by 
$$(a+bx)(c+dx)=ac+(ad+bc)x.$$ And let the norm $\|.\|$ on $A$ be 
$$\|(a+bx)\|=|a|+|b|.$$ Then $(A,\|.\|)$ is a commutative unital Banach algebra.
They say that $(A,\|.\|)$ has only one maximal ideal, i.e the set of $a+bx$ such that $a=0$. Can anyone tell why? How exactly does one identify the maximal ideal space of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of looking at this:

> > **True Fact:** If $\psi:\Bbb C[x]\to\Bbb C$ is a non-zero homomorphism then there exists $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ such that $\psi(p)=p(\alpha)$ for all $p$.

The True Fact is presumably well known, and if you know the True Fact the result follows:

Note first that the multiplication in $A$ can be described as follows: "Multiply $p$ and $q$ using ordinary polynomial multiplication and then discard the $x^2$ term in the product." That says that

> > $A\simeq\Bbb C[x]/<x^2>$.

Now say $I$ is a maximal ideal in $A$. The magic of Banach algebras says that $I$ is the kernel of some homomorphism onto $\Bbb C$ instead of just onto some field. If $j:\Bbb C[x]\to\Bbb C[x]/<x^2>$ is the canonical homomorphism then $\psi=j\circ\phi$ is a complex homomorphism  of $\Bbb C[x]$. So there exists $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with $\psi(p)=p(\alpha)$. But $j(x^2)=0$, hence $\psi(x^2)=0$, hence $\alpha=0$.

Ok, here's a proof of the True Fact. Although I should say that if it's algebra and *I* can figure it out then anyone who knows some algebra should  have no problem:

> > **Lemma:** If $F$ is an algebraically closed field and $I$ is a proper ideal in $F[x]$ then there exists $\alpha\in F$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$ for all $p\in I$.

Proof: Assume wlog that $I\ne0$. Suppose that the polynomials in $I$ have no common zero. Let $p_1\in I$, $p_1\ne0$. Since $p_1$ has only finitely many zeroes there exist $p_2,\dots,p_n\in I$ such that $p_1,\dots,p_n$ have no common zero.

Since $F$ is algebraically closed this says that $p_1,\dots,p_n$ have no common factor; since $F[x]$ is a PID it follows that $I=F[x]$.

A stronger version of the True Fact follows immediately:\

> > **Corollary:** If $F$ is an algebraically closed and $I$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$ then there exists $\alpha\in F$ such that $I=\{p:p(\alpha)=0\}$.

Proof: The lemma says that there exists $\alpha$ such that $I\subset\{p:p(\alpha)=0\}$; since $I$ is maximal we must have $I=\{p:p(\alpha)=0\}$.

Comment: Just confirming.. So $\mathcal{M_A}=\{\alpha\}=\{0\}$?

Comment: @user531706 In the slightly informal notation that people tend to use here, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, maximal ideals are not typically unique. They are just (proper) ideals that cannot be further extended without becoming the entire set.

Let $I$ be the proposed maximal ideal. You need to show, of course, that $I$ is an ideal. It's not hard to show that it's closed under addition, scalar multiplication, and multiplication by any other element of $A$.

It is also maximal, since if we take an ideal $J$ properly containing $I$, then some $a_0x + b_0$ exists in $J \setminus I$, i.e. where $b_0 \neq 0$. But then $-a_0x \in I$ and hence in $J$ too, so $a_0x + b_0 - a_0x = b_0 \in J$. Using the property of ideals, we also have $b_0^{-1} b_0 = 1 \in J$. Therefore, given any $ax + b \in A$, we have $(ax + b)1 \in J$, that is $J = A$.

Next, you need to show that $I$ is the only maximal ideal. Suppose $J$ is some arbitrary maximal ideal of $A$. Note that if $0x + b \in A$, and $b \neq 0$, then the above argument shows $J = A$. More generally, if we have $ax + b \in A$ with $b \neq 0$, then we have
$$(ax + b)(-ax + b) = b^2 \in J,$$
with $b^2 \neq 0$, and hence $J = A$. Thus, if $ax + b \in J$, then $b = 0$, so $J \subseteq I$. From maximality of $J$, we conclude $J = I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is also said that that the maximal ideal space of the above banach algebra can be identified with the origin in the complex plane. Can you tell how? If you want, I can add this in the main question.

Comment: I don't really understand that comment, to be honest. :-/

Comment: Ok. I will try to write it this way. Can I say that the image of the Gelfand transform of $A$, denoted by $\hat A$ is basically $C(M_A)$, Where $M_A$ is a singleton, which can be identified with the origin in the plane?

Comment: Say $\phi$ is the complex homomorphism with kernel $I$. Then $\phi(x)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$. So  if $p=a+bx$ then $\phi(p)=a=p(0)$.